# How to open facebook login dialog in the same window instead of popup window?

Tags: facebook, authentication, popup

I have website where users can login with their Facebook account. 
I am using javascript FB.login method to display Facebook login dialog. By default, it triggers displaying new popup window. Many users have forbidden popups in their browser. How to force facebook login dialog to be displayed in the same window where the user clicked on Login button? 
I can see that it works on this [website](http://www.buddysport.sk/)

When user click on Login button, he is redirected to facebook. After he login to FB, he is redirected back to the original website. Everything in the same browser tab.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Rather than using the FB.login(), just add a link to your page like this:

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL&state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE&scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES">LOGIN!</a>`

Facebook will then log the user in and redirect them back to your URL with some goodies on the querystring:

```
YOUR_REDIRECT_URI?
    error_reason=user_denied
   &error=access_denied
   &error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.
   &state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE
```

Comment: I try this way, but only got these parameters after facebook refirect back to my URI "granted_scopes=email,public_profile&denied_scopes#_=_", what should I do next ? Any suggestions are welcome~

Comment: Thank you, This saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

As per the Facebook [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) you can use `display=page` which will open in same browser window.

Comment: I got an error: `"display" must be one of "popup", "dialog", "iframe", "touch", "async", "hidden", or "none"`

Answer (score 0):

set display touch do the trick

example

```
form method="get" action="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize" id="openid_form">       
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="client_id" id="client_id"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="touch" name="display" id="display"/>

    <input type="hidden" value="http://www.mobileborg.com/modules/openid/fb_callbackuri.php" name="redirect_uri" id="redirect_uri"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="email,read_stream,user_location,user_hometown,read_friendlists,user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access" name="scope" id="scope"/>

    <div style="display:block">
    <input type="hidden" name="oid_name" id="oid_name"/>
    <input type="hidden" size="40" class="openid-identifier" name="openid_identifier" id="openid_identifier"/>
    <input type="submit" style="display:none" value="Login" id="submit-button"/>
    </div>
</form
```

Comment: thank you for answer. I would prefer solution where you don't use a form. I have div element with attached onclick event. After user clicks on div (login button), FB.login method is called.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had the "[External Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/extlink)" module enabled. It saw the facebook url as external, and promptly added target="_blank", causing all clicks to open in a new window.